# how can I autoamate variable input array lists

Tags: c, arrays, list, precompiler

I need to call a series of functions that require a list in  an input array as  following:

```
1st call to func:
custom_type_t inarray = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
2nd call to func:
custom_type_t inarray = {11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};
...
```

How can I pack this into a function that I can call with a particular argument, that will extract the numbers and populate the array accordingly?
Should I use the precompiler accordingly? Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(int i = 1; i < 11; i++) inarray[i - 1] = i;

for(int i = 11; i < 21; i++) inarray[i - 11] = i;
```